# post a json object using guzzle client in guzzle2

Tags: php, web-services, guzzle

I've to post JSON object to webservice using guzzle2.
My service description looks like this :

```
<command name="postJsonData" method="POST" uri="http://10.100.54.12:8580/api/v1/domains/pn/userProfileUpdate">
```

Array of my data I want to send as JSON object looks like this:

```
$abc = array("userProfileUpdateRequest" => array ("vsid" => "123",
       "channelDetails" => array (
        array ("productOfferingId" => "1", "vospScode" => "S123", "productHandle" => "sports" ), array ("productOfferingId" => "2", "vospScode" => "S234", "productHandle" => "kids") ) ) );
```

My question is how to set params for this JSON object in my `webservice.xml` and how to pass this `JSON` object via client.

Please keep in mind, I am using `guzzle2`.

Answer (score 3):

When you do your post() to your guzzle client, use json_encode($abc) as your third parameter.

Comment: thats it !? no need to specify all the indices in array as params in webservice command ?